# SpringMvc - java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, datasource

I am getting the following error when trying to set the dataSource i am using Spring 3.0 under is my code:

**Error**

```
520  [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'countryManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'countryDao' while setting bean property 'countryDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'countryDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcCountryDAO]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcCountryDAO.<init>()
```

**JdbcCountryDAO.java**

```
@Repository
public class JdbcCountryDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport implements CountryDAO{

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());


    @Autowired
    JdbcCountryDAO(DataSource dataSource){
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    public List<Country> getCountryList() {
        int countryId = 6;
        String countryCode = "AI";
        logger.debug("In getCountryList()");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM TBLCOUNTRY WHERE countryId = ? AND countryCode = ?";
        logger.debug("Executing getCountryList String "+sql);

        Object[] parameters = new Object[] {countryId, countryCode};

        logger.info(sql);

        //List<Country> countryList = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,new CountryMapper());

        List<Country> countryList = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, parameters,new CountryMapper());
        return countryList;
    }
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

  <bean id="countryManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.CountryManager">
        <property name="countryDao" ref="countryDao"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="countryDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcCountryDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
<bean id="countryDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcCountryDAO">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

The `dataSource` is not a property of `JdbcCountryDAO` class, it is a constructor argument. Spring says to you: `No default constructor found`, because this is not the default constructor:

```
@Autowired
JdbcCountryDAO(DataSource dataSource){
    setDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

It has a `DataSource` as an argument.

Comment: Paulius Matulionis is absolutely right here. You should update your `applicationContext.xml` configuration by introducing `constructor-arg` for data source reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the error moght be simply that the scope of constructor of your  JdbcCountryDAO is default scope, you need to set it to `public`.

Comment: Constructor annotated with @Autowired annotation does not have to be public. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html